# Updating renovate package lock file and package json file are not in sync

Tags: renovate

I am new to using renovate. I have currently used basic configurations for the renovate bot.
It is working fine but I observed that on one of our repo, package.json and package-lock.json are not in sync.  There is PR raised for package-lock.json but not yet for package.json. Without both of them updated at the same time, the pipeline will fail.
Is this a common behavior of renovate or is there any configuration that I can use to make sure that both the files are updated at the same time.

Comment: {
    "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
    "extends": [
      "config:recommended"      
      ],
      "minimumReleaseAge": "3 days",
      "rangeStrategy": "update-lockfile",
      "labels": [
        "dependencies"
      ], 
      "prConcurrentLimit": 5,
      "rebaseWhen": "conflicted"
  }

Comment: I have the same issue! I can't figure it out. Please post your answer is you managed to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that the update of the package-lock.json failed and
you get an error message with the result of npm update .

e.g. here: https://github.com/ecamp/ecamp3/pull/4056#issuecomment-1807241448